# Differentiate Angular tags from 3rd part tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular

We are trying a use a plugin from 3rd party which use the same syntax as angular component
eg. `<offer></offer>` which needs to be added in Angular templates, since angular detects these as component selectors which are not created , it throws error.

Is there any solution to differentiate or mark the 3rd party tags to be not compiled by Angular ?

Comment: Would ngNonBindable work for this scenario? 
Not 100% sure.

Comment: i was searching for the right term! thanks @TonyB